# IntelliJ: Change the color of classes or data types for Java

Tags: java, intellij-idea

How do I change the color of the `class` or `data type`
in IntelliJ?

[image]

I set the values ​​I want to modify and apply the changes, but it just does not reflect in the code. It only lets me set the values ​​of the **Strings**, **comments** or **numbers**. I leave a screenshot so you can see what I'm trying to do.

Example:

[image]

Comment: why doesn't Intellij make this the default? like other IDEs, VSCode, eclipse, etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi guys this problem was due to an error in the java JDK installation, I just reinstalled the JDK and the IDE worked normal.

Comment: Please edit your answer instead of put new post in discussion.

Comment: Uhh... What's with all the "please edit" comments? This _is_ an answer. OP solved their problem by reinstalling the JDK, and posted an answer saying so. **Which is the right thing to do**. If this was an edit to the question, comments would go *"Please don't include your solution in the question, instead post an answer blah blah"* and the edit would probably be rolled back.

Answer (score 3):

In IntelliJ, navigate to: `Settings > Editor > Color Scheme > Language Defaults > Classes > Class name`.

Then untick `Inherit values from:`. Then change the `Foreground` color.

You may change any colors you want under this tab. And don't forget to apply.

[image]

Comment: I do it as you say, but it still does not reflect the changes.

Comment: @DanielBaez You need to select the correct `Scheme` as well. As you can see in the top of the window in my screenshot. For example, if you use the Darcula theme, you need to select the Darcula scheme there.

Comment: Ok, apparently this property does not let me make the changes I want. But if I disable it, it remains the same https://i.imgur.com/AlhsblP.png

Comment: Thanks, I'll keep trying

Comment: @DanielBaez Your screenshot has cropped the top part of the window so I can't see what is selected.

Comment: Hi again, I could not directly solve the problem but when creating a new project if you can visualize the changes. I saw that I am not the only one. https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000690850-Can-t-change-color-schemes-in-IntelliJ-IDEA-2017-2-5

Comment: @DanielBaez Are you sure you're changing the colors in a scheme which is currently active? Don't you have a different scheme active than you're modifying?

Comment: why doesn't Intellij make this the default? like other IDEs, VSCode, eclipse, etc

Answer (score 3):

Can you try following steps.

- Duplicate the existing theme.

[image]

- Uncheck the `Inherit values from` and choose color in Foreground and Background from `Editor > Color Scheme > Java`

[image]

- Don't forget to save and apply.

[image]

- Make sure that you are using your custom scheme. You can also use on windows `` ctrl+` >> color scheme >> your custom scheme ``. In my case it was test.